# WebAssembly.JSException: TypeError: Failed to fetch when server does not response

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

I want to write code for case when server does not response.
I purposely shutdown backend to simulate this situation. `HttpClient` throws `WebAssembly.JSException` with message

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Is it OK?

I think it is confusing.
I afraid if I will depend from this behavior, there will be problems.
How can I properly handle this case?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: There is  "WebAssembly.JSException: TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Comment: Are you using http or https?

Comment: I am using https

Comment: Is it working when you use only http?

Comment: I purposely shutdown backend to simulate the situation when server does not response.

Comment: I have not tried http

Comment: Is this a normal Wasm client or a PWA ?

Comment: normal Wasm client

Comment: Just handle the exception...  I don't see much of a problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet describes how you perform an HTTP GET call to a Web Api endpoint, querying the value of IsSuccessStatusCode which indicates whether the HTTP response was successful or not. If successful, the code retrieves the data stream, deserialize it into a `List<Contact>`, and returns it to the calling code.

If not successful (else clause), handle failure...here you can place whatever checking you want to make, logging errors, displaying messages, etc.

What I'm trying to show here is the direction how to solve not only that issue of yours, but other exception such as NotFound ( 404 ) exception, etc.

You may also use the response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); in a try/catch block and handles exceptions according to your needs.

You can do all this in various manners...

```
public async Task<List<Contact>> GetContactsAsync()
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/contacts");
           // response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               // Handle success
                  var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Contact>>(responseContent);
           }
           else
           {
              // Handle failure
           }
            
        }
```

Comment: This code works perfect, if the response exists. If it doesn't code throws `WebAssembly.JSException`.

Comment: So handle the exception. As I've mentioned above. The solution is the direction I'm providing here. I'm not going to prescribe a concise solution to an issue without code. JUST WHERE TO LOOK FOR THE SOLUTION. Please note that what you are facing has nothing to do with http/https...

Comment: I can handle this exception, no problem. A problem is strange `HttpClient` behavior.  I believe it will bring me a problems. Maybe, should I go to aspnet github and post an issue?

Comment: Now you are digressing from the main subject of your question... No issue, you may post your issue in stackoverflow and in github as well. Don't expect to get better answers there, not even from the asp.net teams, who very often redirect folks to stackoverflow, unless the issue in question is evidently of the nature of a bug. However, you should provide complete repo of your code, and state clearly what you do and what you expect to be done...